# How to fix the antd card position?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, antd

I want my antd card to be displayed in the center. When I click a button, this card needs to be displayed and it also needs to aligned in the centre.
I have written the code to make it work  like that but soon after I click the button, the card first gets displayed on the left and then comes to the center. How do I avoid this? I want the  card to be displayed in the center directly on a button click.

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);


<div>
<Button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>Hi</Button>
{show ? (

  <Col style={{ height: "750px", width: "100%" }}>
    <Card className="cardStyle">
      <p>Card title will come here!!!</p>
    </Card>
  </Col>
) : null}
</div>
```

Css:

```
.cardStyle {
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 300px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Is if because of existing css for other components?

Comment: can you create a minimal eg on codesanbox or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to apply some styling to your column to center it and its contents. Using transform and top/left positioning isn't going to be all that consistent here.

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/DMcCallum83/pen/wvEqMQR?editors=0110) showing your code, but I've moved the styling for the column in to css and added flex position:

```
.colStyle {
  height: 750px; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cardStyle {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: My previous css was overwriting the styling for this. After I corrected that and with the properties mentioned here, I am able to fix it in the center.